# Adding Prig Assembly for mscorlib

Tags: unit-testing, x86, .net-assembly, mscorlib, target-platform

I'm trying to use prig to shim methods from mscorlib and target the x86 platform.

I have prig set up and it works fine with System, but for mscorlib things work a little differently. I'm trying to shim Random.next() to test specific results.

I can get mscorlib.prig to load when I change my default processor architecture to X64 in the test menu, but the rest of the application targets X86, so the projects I wish to test won't all load.

I've tried renaming some files from AMD64 to x86, but I have no idea what I'm doing here.

I'm using prig v2.3.2

When I Add Prig Assembly For mscorlib, I get two references, mscorlib.v4.0.30319.v4.0.0.0.AMD64.Prig and mscorlib.v4.0.30319.v4.0.0.0.x86.Prig.

I can view the AMD64 one in the object browser, but the x86 one has a little warning symbol and when I double click, I get an error that it is unavailable or not yet built.

I'm assuming that it only builds the AMD64 oen because I have an x64-based processor on the machine I'm developing on, but I need it to build for x86.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work, not really sure what exactly did it, but one of these things probably did it.

I changed the platform for the unit test project to the platform x86.
I changed my environment variable for Processor_Architecture to x86 in the registry.

I'm leaning more toward the first one. Hope this helps someone.